# Storing objects in session

Tags: java, session, servlets

I have a PersistenceCapable class

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class MyClass
{
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
         ..........
         ..........
}
```

In my servlet, I need to store object of this class in session

```
............
MyClass u = new MyClass();
......
......
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("SV", u);
........
```

I am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException:`

What is this?

Comment: Can you make your PersistenceCapable class Serializable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sessions can be temporarily stored on disk or migrated to another application server. In order to make sure that objects in the session can be handled in those situations they need to be serailisable. You can flag this by implementing the `Serializable` interface:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyClass implements Serializable {
}
```

Comment: Can you show me where i can write the flag to make it serializable?

Comment: @Manjoor - `public class MyClass implements Serializable`

Answer (score 1):

[rsp is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370680/storing-objects-in-session-java-servlet/3370733#3370733): Serializable is the correct answer, but implementing Serializable is only the first step. E.g. you need to also make all fields either Serializable or transient.

Read one of the [many](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) [about](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20050923/IntroductionToObjectSerialization.html) [Java](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20050923/IntroductionToObjectSerialization.html) [Serialization](http://www.javabeginner.com/object-serialization.htm), or best of all: buy [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/index.html) by Joshua Bloch and read all of it, including the 4 chapters about Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I guess putting a bunch of annotations in your class does not make it implement the Serializable interface. Why should it? Do `public class MyClass implements Serializable { ...`

Comment: it could, if there was an annotation processor present that modified the source code. But I guess there isn't

Comment: In OP's example we have:
`MyClass u = new MyClass();
......
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);` which does not leave much room for annotation processor